# How to hide the form elements if the field is empty in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using `OpenStruct form for` in my view like the following,

```
<%= form_for(OpenStruct.new(params[:f]), as: :f, url: product_types_path, method: :get, remote: true, html: {class: 'type'}) do |f| %>     
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :product_type_id %>    
    <%= foreign_key(f, :product_type_id, Asset::Product::Type) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to hide the other form elements if `product_type_id is nil or blank or empty?`

I tried this,

```
<% unless product_type_id.blank? %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <p>Select Product Type</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: id can't be empty, empty is for arrays. So what you did should work fine? Don't understand the problem...

Comment: just create your object `OpenStruct.new(params[:f]` before hand.

Answer (score 0):

So if I got it right what you want to do is not to render the form if what you received with the param `product_type_id` is blank.

Is it possible for you to instatiate the variable in the controller instead of defining it directly in the form builder?

For instance in your controller:

```
def index
  @product_type = OpenStruct.new(params[:f])
end
```

and in your view:

```
<% unless @product_type.product_type_id.blank? %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= render 'form', product_type: @product_type %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <p>Select Product Type</p>
<% end %>
```

and finally your partial:

```
<%= form_for(product_type), as: :f, url: product_types_path, method: :get, remote: true, html: {class: 'type'}) do |f| %>     
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :product_type_id %>    
    <%= foreign_key(f, :product_type_id, Asset::Product::Type) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```